# How to properly add `Drawer` to `StatefulShellRoute`

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, flutter-go-router

How do I properly add a drawer to [this example](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart) while keeping the tab specific app bar? When I add one to the `Scaffold` on one of the pages it works, but the `Drawer` is not the full vertical size of the screen (only top of the nav bar and up).

But when I add it to the `Scaffold` of the `ScaffoldWithNavBar` widget it doesn't show up at all unless I also add an `AppBar`, which will then conflict with the page specific `AppBar`...

Is it possible to get the `Drawer` on one of the branches to become the full vertical screen?